# When is an e-mail too trivial to be sent?

Tags: professionalism, email

My question concerns whether it is too trivial to send a reply to an email in some cases.

In this example, the e-mail converstation is this:

---

Me: Hi boss, the status of the project I am working on is X *(long description)*. FYI, I will not be able to work as much in the next two months due to heavy workload in university.

Boss: Hi John, thank you very much for your thorough status. No problem at all with the reduced hours - feel free to take as much time off as you need. :) We'll figure it out.

---

So essentially the response I received from my boss was "All good - OK, no problem."
Is it normal to respond to this kind of mail?
I could write something like

"You're welcome, I figured a proper status would be useful to you. Thank you for your understanding."

Or I could choose not to respond. Would that be considered rude?
I find myself thinking about similar email correspondences, and sometimes I'm simply not sure whether sending such a simple "OK, thank you." e-mail is necessary. Perhaps the recipient would feel that it is unnecessary and clutters up his inbox. On the other hand, I do not wish to appear disrespectful.

What is considered normal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under what circumstances to send a "you're welcome" email?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98056/under-what-circumstances-to-send-a-youre-welcome-email)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to send a "thank you" email?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3750/when-to-send-a-thank-you-email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is fine. It is the same as in spoken conversation: when someone says "thank you," is it proper to respond with "you're welcome", or to stay silent? Either choice is okay; whichever you choose, the world is not going to end. You are not going to get fired for choosing to say "you're welcome" or not to.

> What is considered normal?

There is no universal, correct, "normal" way. Communication is a [soft skill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_skills). Try out a few different methods, try imitating others' methods that you admire, see what works and what doesn't. Gradually you will develop your own personal style which, whether or not it is "normal", will be what works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just go with the simple:

> Many thanks for the support, I really appreciate it

I'm not sure you need more.  You might want to wish him a good weekend if you send this on a Friday.